# jQuery. What happens to click, then page resizes

Tags: jquery, resize, window

I need to disable click, when page is lower than 1100px width. But if user decides to make it larger, then I need to re-enable it. I have this code, but it does not work, if you resize page to more than 1100px;

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {  
    if ($(window).width() < 1100)
    {
        $('.portfolio-box-caption, .portfolio-box, .popup-gallery, .container-fluid').click(function(){
            return false;
        });
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > 1100)
    {
        $('.portfolio-box-caption, .portfolio-box, .popup-gallery, .container-fluid').click(function(){
            return true;
        });
    }
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the click event and then unbind it. Checking the size of the page on load will determine where you start.

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

```
$( "#foo" ).bind( "click", function() {
    alert( "User clicked on 'foo.'" );
});
```

Think of the functions attached to a selector as a list, and they all get executed depending on which event fired. With your code, you are appending to the 'lists' with each resize, and never clearing them.

Comment: Even though your answer was not in great detail, it showed me the right way!

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `off()` and `on()` and a global var Boolean:

```
var clickAdded = ($(window).width() >= 1100) ? true : false,
    w = window;
$(window).on('resize', function () {  

    if ($(w).width() < 1100)
    {
        $('.portfolio-box-caption, .portfolio-box, .popup-gallery, .container-fluid').off('click');
        w.clickAdded = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (!w.clickAdded) {
            $('.portfolio-box-caption, .portfolio-box, .popup-gallery, .container-fluid').on('click', function(){
                w.clickAdded = true;
                //your JS
            });
        }
    }
});
```

To prevent multiple click handlers from adding, you need a check to see if it was already added (because resize event will still fire if window keeps enlarging past 1100px)

Comment: I have not managed to make your code to work. But I got the idea, thanks for that!